# PowerShell passing variable name instead of variable content

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to retrieve a specific registry value from multiple machines where names are stored in the table `$Workstations`. The OS is Server 2008.
Here's the script:

```
foreach ($Workstation in $Workstations)
$WorkstationName = $Workstation.name  
$query = "\\"+$WorkstationName+"\HKLM\Software\[FULL PATH] /v [VALUE]"
reg query $query
```

Unfortunatly this returns an `invalid key name` error. My guess is that the `reg query` command is not parsing the variable correctly and therefore executes `reg query $query` as is. I tried to use some quotes combiantions, passing `WorkstationName` directly to `reg query` without success. But if I `Write-Output $query` and copy-paste the output directly to a manually entered `reg query` command it does work perfectly.

Any clue ?
Thanks

Comment: I couldnt understand the logic fully. 



$query = "\\"+$WorkstationName+"\HKLM\Software\[FULL PATH] /v [VALUE]"



What is [Full Path] and [VALUE] on the above line?

Comment: It's the full path to the registry key and /v is for the key itself. As the complete path shows some explicit content about the company I work for, I prefer to hide it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the arguments to `reg.exe` *individually*, which you can easily do by defining `$query` as an *array*, for instance:

```bash
$query = "\\"+$WorkstationName+"\HKLM\Software\[FULL PATH]", 
         '/v', 
         '[VALUE]'

reg query $query
```